# AngularJS add and use dynamic appeared HTML to controller scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Faced a problem with adding dynamically generated HTML to controller's scope and using of it. Here is my other topic([generated AngularJS controller usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462408/generated-angularjs-controller-usage?noredirect=1#comment49028910_30462408)) but the task is little but different now(don't need to generate HTML controller's initialization, can be done without it).

The thing is - If i dynamically add controller in this example - i can get `alert()` (controller works) on controller's initialization, but not on the click_btn() and other actions.
If i just adding a HTML to statically defined controller - same issue. Don`t get any errors, tried both $scope & $RootScope options.

I tried a lot of combinations & variants. Currently adding here an example with `angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($compile) { -  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'invoke' of undefined`  error.

Here is the example where i'm trying to get it work. easy structure and example.

```js
//////////////////////
///Controller Definition (located in different .js file)
//////////////////////
angular.module('MainPage', [])
  .controller('Hello', function($scope, $http) {
    alert('fsdfsdfsd12121212');
    $scope.click_btn = function() {
      alert('fsdfsdfsd');
    }
  });

//////////////////////
///JS FILE from where i need to add HTML to scope and page content
//////////////////////

var contentString =
  '<button ng-click="click_btn()">Load Data!</button>';

AddElementAngular(contentString);

function AddElementAngular(html) {


  angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
    var scope = angular.element(html).scope();
    $compile(html)(scope);
    $(document.body).append(html);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="MainPage">

<head>
  <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="Hello">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Seeking for help, so stuck on it, very important thing to continue.
Also have to mention that i can't use iserting HTML by using angular directives, cause i need to put some variables from .js to the `var contentString` + Angular need to be initialized on the page load, so i con't wait before the call of this js func and only then initialize angular.

Actual JS is much bigger and have a lot of func. Here it's just an example for the problem.

Comment: couldn't you use different directives with own scopes/templates?

Comment: already metion about it 'Also have to mention that i can't use inserting HTML by using angular directives, cause i need to put some variables from .js to the var contentString'

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question,
the newly created DOM element does not inherit the $scope given to its compiled template.

as long as you have a valid reference to the scope you want the new DOM element to be under, You can do similar to what U did above or create a new scope for the element and then extend it with the parent scope:

```
var scope = angular.element(html).scope();
    $.extend(scope, $parentScope)
```